# i found this error when i run this java code

Tags: java

```
class Factorial
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        int num=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int result=1;
        while(num>0)
        {
            result=result*num;
            num--;
        }
        System.out.println("Factorial of Given Number is :" +result);
    }
}
```

It is showing the error as follows :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>           at Factorial.main(factorial.java:5)

Comment: That's what happens when you don't give the program a command line argument.

Comment: How are you running this program? Are you passing any parameter to it? If yes, how?

Comment: Please edit your title to something useful and descriptive of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to run this code with a command line argument :

```
java Factorial 5
```

In addition, to make you program more user friendly, I'd suggest you check that `args.length > 0` before trying to access `args[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code as follows

```
class Factorial {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      if(args[0].length > 0) {
        int num=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int result=1;
        while(num>0)
        {
            result=result*num;
            num--;
        }
        System.out.println("Factorial of Given Number is :" +result);
     } else {
      System.out.println("Your message requesting a number");
     }
    }
}
```

Run the program with an argument.

```
Ex: java Factorial 5
```

If you do not parse any argument the "Your message requesting a number" will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure what you pass an argument while executing the program like:

```
 java fact 10
```